# Reading csv file on s3 in dask

Tags: pandas, dask

I am able to read a csv that's located on s3 in pandas successfully as follows:

```
 pdf=pd.read_csv('s3a:///bucket/input_file.csv')
```

However, if I try to do the same in dask as follows:

```
 ddf=dd.read_csv('s3a:///bucket/input_file.csv')
```

but I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-29-07e2d394bb38> in <module>()
----> 1 ddf=dd.read_csv('s3a:///bucket/input_file.csv')

/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io.pyc in read_csv(fn, **kwargs)
 220         return concat([read_csv(f, **kwargs) for f in sorted(glob(fn))])
221
--> 222     token = tokenize(os.path.getmtime(fn), kwargs)
223     name = 'read-csv-%s-%s' % (fn, token)
224     bom = get_bom(fn, kwargs.get('compression', None))

...

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'s3a:///bucket/input_file.csv'
```

I've also tried using:

```
 ddf=dd.read_csv('s3://bucket/input_file.csv')
```

and get the same error.

Comment: Can you check that you have `s3fs` installed?

Comment: I just installed s3fs and still get the same errors.

```In [8]: print s3fs.__version__
0.0.7```

Comment: ... (nevermind)